# How do access derived data through down casting?

Tags: c++

Why can't I do the following code without getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error?
So `p_base` is an array of pointers to base class. The pointers in the array point to 3 different class objects which all have their own data and base data.

In the code below, I'm trying to down cast the base pointer to one of the derived class pointer so I can access one of that object's attributes to sum up `bank_fees`.

Since I don't know which iteration contains a `derived1` object, I used a loop to down cast all of the object pointers but its not correct.  How do I downcast just the base class pointer to derived1 without knowing which iteration derived1 objects are at?

```
class base{

protected:
   string transaction_date_;
   int transaction_id_;
   double transaction_amount_;
public:
    Transaction();
    Transaction(string,int,double);

//Pure virtual function
    virtual void Display() const = 0;
}

class derived1{
private:
    double fee_charge_;
public: 
    double get_fee_charge() const{
        return fee_charge_; 
    };
    void set_fee_charge(double fee){
        fee_charge_ = fee;
    };
    virtual void Display() const;
}


void Customer::method(){
double bank_fees = 0;

derived *p_derived1 = new derived1;

for(int i =0;i<16;i++){
    p_base[i]->Display();
    p_derived1 = dynamic_cast<derived*>(p_base[i]);
    bank_fees += p_derived1->get_fee_charge();
}

cout << bank_fees;
}
```

Comment: The declarations of the class structure would help

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) (especially point 5c of the **Explanation**)? If the cast fails (which will be the case since not all the pointers point to `derived1` objects), it returns `nullptr` which you are trying to dereference.

Comment: Please give us enough code to replicate the issue.

Comment: Down casting dangerously circumvents type checking.  In 20+ years of C++, I dare say I have never 'downcast'.  Better alternatives exist.  The alternative I like is to simply add the method interface (of the derived class) to the base class ... usually these have an implementation that simply asserts.  Only the derived class that needs the method should perform it, others should simply default to allow the base class to assert.

Answer (score 0):

After you `downcast`, you need to check whether it was successful before using the pointer.

```
p_derived1 = dynamic_cast<derived1*>(p_base[i]);
if ( p_derived1 != nullptr )
{
   bank_fees += p_derived1->get_fee_charge();
}
```

Also, you don't need

```
derived1 *p_derived1 = new derived1;
```

That results in a memory leak. You can remove that line completely and declare `p_derived1` in the loop itself.

```
derived1* p_derived1 = dynamic_cast<derived1*>(p_base[i]);
if ( p_derived1 != nullptr )
{
   bank_fees += p_derived1->get_fee_charge();
}
```

Comment: The need to remember to "check if successful" (and handle when it does not) is why I don't downcast.  In this case, I would add the method "get_fee_charge()" to base, with only an assert in it, and only the p_derived instance would implement the 'real' get_fee_charge(). All other derived classes ignore the method.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN, I don't think that's the OP's intent. `p_base` potentially has pointers to objects which are instances of classes other than `derived1`.